# assigning setting onClick listener imageview dynamically

Tags: android

I am working on an application where hundreds of Image Views are being used and I want to set the onClick listener  and assignment dynamically
but unfortunately i am getting Null Pointer Exception
the code is shown below

```
ImageView simageView1, simageView2, simageView3, simageView4, simageView5;  
ImageView[] imgViewArray = { simageView1, simageView2, simageView3,
        simageView4, simageView5 };  
for (int i = 0; i < imgViewArray.length; i++) {
        int integere = i+1;
        String imageViewName = "simageView" + integere;
        Log.d("tag", "name of the ImageView are " +imageViewName);
        imgViewArray[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(getResources()
                .getIdentifier(imageViewName, "id", getPackageName()));
         imgViewArray[i].setOnClickListener(this);
```

i am getting NullPointerException

Comment: Show the stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: where you initialized these Objects.   ImageView simageView1, simageView2, simageView3, simageView4, simageView5;

Comment: i am trying to initialize them dynamically in the loop

Comment: `getResources().getIdentifier(imageViewName, "id", getPackageName())` returning zero. So, findViewById(0) doesn't return any imageview and you got `imageView[0]` as `null`.

Comment: but when i use the same concept outside the loop it do not make any error

Comment: String imageViewName = "simageView" +1;
   simageView1= (ImageView) findViewById(getResources()
   .getIdentifier(imageViewName, "id", getPackageName()));
   simageView1.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: It will not give you any error also if you comment `setOnClickListner(this)` at next line, It doesn't depend on loop. In above comment, `simageView1` is null, when you use this object for further operation it will give you `NullPointerException`

Comment: if i want to use only    setOnClickListner(this)  outside the loop the progrma crashes

Answer (score 0):

Hundreds of ImageViews? 
Sounds like you should use a ListView / GridView /RecyclerView with an adapter and an onItemClicked listener. 
I think this would be much better.

See:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: if i want to use the same technique then what is the error in my code

Comment: I think getResources().getIdentifier(imageViewName, "id", getPackageName()) is a hack that should not be used. Future android version might change this and your code won't work. I think @Manish Dubey is right. It will return 0.

Comment: when i use this it work like Charm   String imageViewName = "simageView" +1;
   simageView1= (ImageView) findViewById(getResources()
   .getIdentifier(imageViewName, "id", getPackageName()));
   simageView1.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: If you handle "hundreds of imageViews" this way (without an adapter) you will run into OutOfMemory problems.

Comment: add a Log.d("tag", getResources()
                .getIdentifier(imageViewName, "id", getPackageName())) line to your code and verify that 0 is never returned

Comment: what is the parent layout of the image views?

Comment: hmmm.... ok but can u give me some suggestions if i wnat to init and set onClick listener in a loop for other program because i am eager to do some thing like that

Comment: There is no such thing as an ID for a Drawable created at runtime. Those IDs refer to int fields in the R class, automatically created from the xml files.

Comment: Have you any drawable in your res/drawable folder named as "simageView" or "simageView2" and so on... ?